# reinterpret cast between structure and integer and correct or incorrect behaviour of compiler

Tags: c++

Here the question is if the behaviour of some compilers is correct and standard.

My understanding of the reinterpret_cast ( I may be wrong ) is that when `A a;B b;` then `reinterpret_cast<A>b` is equivalent to `*((A*)&b)`.

According to that vision the code bellow should work but in `g++` it doesn't is it standard ?

```
struct A{
    int a;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct A x;
  x.a=5;
  int b=*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);
// the previous works but it should work as bellow
  int b=reinterpret_cast<int>(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that really what you are trying to compile?

Comment: That doesn't even compile, because that's not how you use reinterpret_cast and you can't use return; in a statement that epects a return-value.

Comment: reinterpret_cast<x> ??? should be int b = reinterpret_cast<int>(x) or better: reinterpret_cast<int&>(x)

Comment: When you do get it to compile, remember it's probably wrong! reinterpret_cast is bad news 99% of the time

Comment: reiterpret_cast<type>(variable) that is how templates work between the < > u put the type

Comment: Sorry for the errors, I should check compilation before posting.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis It still doesn't compile.

Comment: @zyboxinternational Why on earth would one `return NULL` if `main()` returns an `int`?

Comment: @juanchopanza I was giving a basic example that the `return 0;` is basically not returning anything of use.

Comment: Why `return 0;` anyway, there's the exact same as `return;`. I can't see what the OP is trying to get out of the `return 0;`. If you're not returning anything of use, then to my understanding the function should be `void` (well, it would if it wasn't the `main` function).

Comment: @zyboxinternational Come on, `return;` would be illegal. I realise now you don't know what you are talking about, so I will ignore your comments.

Comment: @juanchopanza I was making an example, not that it had to be taken literally. You're slightly on the rude side- you've got tons more rep than me, you know the rules..

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast<A>(b)` is not legal if `A` and `B` are unrelated types (though I vaguely recall that some earlier versions of MSVC might have allowed it). What you're probably looking for is `reinterpret_cast<A const&>(b)`, which likewise reinterprets the bits of `b` as belonging to an `A`. (Or `reinterpret_cast<A&>`, if you want to write to it -- the main point is the reference.)

Comment: Isn't reinterpret_cast well-behaved if both A and B have the exact same layout? I know this is true in C, but I'm not sure if the same applies to C++.

Comment: You'd have to define "well-behaved". I honestly don't know whether it compiles -- I'd use a reference for that too. Assuming it does, it doesn't invoke undefined behavior (just like in C).

Comment: Shokwav: it is legal under certain conditions. For instance, it is legal to `reinterpet_cast` a pointer to an object of a standard-layout class to a pointer of the first non-static data member.

Comment: @peppe It's certainly legal to do it to the pointer. I think Shokwav's point was whether it was legal to cast a non-pointer non-reference if the underlying layout was the same.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast "Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of expression as if it had the type new_type." That using my brain translates exactly to (*<int*>&x) So I am expecting from reinterpret_cast exactly that. WHY NOT ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to do something like this:

```
struct A{int a};

int main(){
    A x;
    x.a = 5;

    int* b = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);
}
```

In which case the answer is no, this is not standard; it is completely UB. Also, in the case of pointers, it also violates strict aliasing ([What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)).

Comment: Yes instead of using what I am thinking should be the "normal" way of doing it: reinterpret_cast<int>x; I am obliged to do int b =*(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x)) and I don't like doing it. So what is reinterpret cast used for ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: reinterpret_cast is when you need to break the rules of the language in order to do something very (platform) specific. It has very few legitimate uses; in fact, the only use case I've ran across was a delegate implementation that used it specifically for handling MSVC's nonstandard behavior. In short: do not use it, unless you REALLY know what you're doing.

Comment: Hmm? AFAICT, the usage you posted here is totally legal. For POD types, the rules for casting and aliasing go by what the underlying basic type is, not what user-defined struct it's in.